# Determining Users on SharePoint website with API?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, app-part

Was thinking about building an app part that enabled some level of in-app messaging to other users currently on the site (probably via use of websockets connections to each other).  Is there any way to figure out who is currently using the SharePoint site at any one time via the AppModel (so JavaScript making calls would have to do).  At least an approximation of who hasn't timed out their login yet?

I was thinking about creating a service that would serve as a directory but I'd like to believe SharePoint somewhere is tracking this.

Comment: If you are planning on using websockets (like SignalR) I guess you can get this information by analyzing who is connected to your socket?

Comment: The trick here would be to track who is capable of establishing a web socket connection to whom...

Comment: Could you not track username and site in the socket?